# using cross ratio to find a Fractional Linear Transformation

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to use cross ratio to find a LFT that sends $1,2,i$ to $i,1,2$ using cross ratios. I have that

$$\frac{(z-2)(1-i)}{i-z}=\frac{(w-1)(i-2)}{(w-2)(i-1)}$$

but how on earth do I solve for $w$? I know if I multiply both sides by a $(i-1)$ I obtain

$$\frac{2i(z-2)}{i-z}=\frac{(w-1)(i-2)}{w-2}$$

and dividing by $(i-2)$ I obtain

$$\frac{2i(z-2)}{(i-z)(i-2)}=\frac{w-1}{w-2}$$

But here I get super stuck. If anyone can help me out please, it would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: You need to use that $i=\frac{z-2}{1-i}\cdot\frac{1-i}{z-i}$ and $2=\frac{w-1}{i-1}\cdot\frac{i-1}{w-i}$ to get $i=\frac{1-2w}{w-2}$ and $2=\frac{1-2i}{i-1}$.
Now, from the first equation, you get $w=\frac{2}{i+1}=\frac{2i}{1+i^2}$ from where you get $w=\frac{2}{i+1}=\frac{2i}{1+i^2}=\frac{2}{\frac{1-2i}{i-1}+1}=\frac{2i}{2i-1}$.

Comment: how did you get that $i$  is equal to that product ? and how did you get that $2$ is equal to the later product and how did you conclude $i = \frac{1-2w}{w-2}$  and $2=\frac{1-2i}{i-1}$ ? @AmirrezaHashemi bebakhshid

Comment: Also, @AmirrezaHashemi where is the $z$ in the final form for $w$?

Comment: The left-hand side of your final equation can just be thought of as some constant.  Now just solve the equation for $w$ in terms of that constant.

Comment: that's where im stuck though @EricWofsey

Comment: I feel compelled to say that you don't really want to try to remember a formula, but, rather, construct _step-wise_ the thing that you want... Formulas tend to be brittle, and immemorable... :)

Comment: Can you solve the equation $3=\frac{w-1}{w-2}$ for $w$?  If so, you can solve your equation (just replace $3$ with the messy thing on the left).

Comment: @EricWofsey that I can do!! but with all the $z$'s and $i$'s it gets super messy!